# Automapper многие ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, relation, automapper

Есть две модели

**Сущность из БД**

Назовём её "Сервис"

```
public class GeneralService {

public GeneralService(){

this.ServiceWorkTypes = new HashSet<ServiceWork>

}
  public override System.Guid Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  internal virtual ICollection<ServiceWork> ServiceWorks { get; set; }

}
```

ещё типы сервисов

```
public class ServiceWorkTypes
{
 public override System.Guid Id { get; set; }

 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

И связанная модель, сервисов и типов работ плюс их стоимость, реализующая логику связи многие-ко-многим

```
public class ServiceWork {

public override System.Guid Id { get; set; }

public System.Guid ServiceWorkTypeId {get;set;}

public System.Guid ServiceId {get;set;}

public int Price {get;set;}
}
```

есть их "зеркала" в виде моделей

```
public class GeneralServiceModel {

  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

 List<ServiceWorksModel> ServiceWorks { get; set; }
}

 public class ServiceWorkModel {

public Guid Id { get; set; }

public Guid ServiceWorkTypeId {get;set;}

public Guid ServiceId {get;set;}

public int Price {get;set;}
}
```

ну и для остальных соответствующее

Проблема в работе automappera для этих моделей,

```
internal static class Mapping
{
    static Mapping()
    {
        RegisterMappings();
    }

    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
    {
        return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    }
Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceWork, ServiceWorkModel >().IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();
Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceWorkTypes, ServiceWorkTypesModel>().IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();
Mapper.CreateMap<GeneralService, GeneralServiceModel>().ForMember( " // вот тут должен быть код маппинга списка работ  но я ничего не могу понять").IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

вот мои DbExtentionService для этих GeneralService

```
public override OperationResult Add(GeneralServiceModel item)
        {

            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

            return DatabaseContext.Run(db =>
            {
                if (GetTable(db).AsNoTracking().Any(r => r.Id == tem.Id))
                    return OperationResult.Fail("Такая запись уже есть");

         var dbEntity = Mapping.Map(item, new DB.RescueService());

         db.SaveChanges();

                return OperationResult.Success();
```

**Итак, основная проблема:**
- Смапить пришедший список List на HashSet
- Подсказать как по чище сделать добавление в DB связанных записей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фундаментальная ошибка, в наименовании списка в Модели и в Образе обьекта базы данных, абсолютно одинаково. 
Модель ServiceWork пришлось переделать и заменить в ней

```
List<ServiceWorksModel> ServiceWorks { get; set; }
```

на

```
List<ServiceWorksModel> ServiceWorksInModel("Или как вам будет угодно") { get; set; }
```

А сам маппер переписать следующим образом

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GeneralService, GeneralServiceModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.ServiceWorks, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ServiceWorks.ToList()))
    .IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter()
    .ReverseMap();
```